# PayPal responds Fatal Failure for some valid payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

When I send the ipn verification request to PayPal it usually works fine, but for some valid payments I am getting 'Fatal Failure' as result instead of 'VERIFIED'.
What can cause this?

This is the code I am using

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . file_get_contents('php://input');
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: could it be bad input?

Comment: Jasen I will start logging the input, but still, that is what PayPal sends to me in the notification. I can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Jasen I can't see anything wrong in the input